# youtube embedded video as iframe with border-radius

Tags: css, iframe, youtube, rounded-corners

I got a problem I absolutely don't understand. I got a website with YouTube video iframe and want to round the borders via CSS. On http://www.wunschpreisdeal.de/empfehlung/winterreifen-profiltiefe-und-zustand-noch-ok the video is correctly embedded with rounded borders but that's not the case on http://www.wunschpreisdeal.de/mitglieder-empfehlung/the-axe-effect.

They both have the same CSS, I haven't found any difference between those integrations. Can anyone help me? If you need some more info, just ask. :)

thx

Comment: On Chrome, border-radius works for none of them.

Comment: Oh, i see. But why is the one working in FF and on the other page not? Or better, is there a way to realize rounded borders in all browser (IE can be excluded ;)).

Comment: You may find some help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535217/css-adding-border-radius-to-an-iframe

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question upfront, the difference between those two pages is the addition of `wmode=transparent` to the `iframe` address like so: `http://www.youtube.com/embed/QKh1Rv0PlOQ?rel=0&wmode=transparent`. That's a quick fix to get you going, but if you'd like to learn a bit more on the subject, then read on!

---

Unfortunately, rounding the corners of embedded videos such as YouTube and Vimeo is quite challenging due to the differences between older browsers. Even wrapping the `iframe` in an outer `div` and applying a `border-radius` and `overflow: hidden` to the wrapper, which works for most `iframes`, doesn't *reliably* do the trick!

> Note: Ivijan-Stefan came up with an elegant solution below that works in most modern browsers, so if your site doesn't need to cater to legacy browsers like Internet Explorer 6 and 7, then feel free to use his implementation instead!

For those of us that need to support a variety of legacy browsers, the only *consistently* reliable way to do this is by making an image that looks like a curved corner, and using copies of this image to cover up each of the corners of the video. (Here's where we require the `wmode=transparent` trick that I described above, since some browsers will otherwise display the corner images *under* the video!)

Here is an example of this technique applied to an `iframe`-embedded YouTube video: http://jsfiddle.net/skywalkar/uyfR6/ (example radius = 20px)

> Note: If you make the corner overlays too large (greater than ~20px), then they will cover up the player controls!
>   To minimize the effects of problem, you can try cutting the corners by rotating the images by 45 degrees. This requires a different set of overlays and some creative use of margins, but may be worth the trouble if you need larger corner radii: http://jsfiddle.net/skywalkar/BPnLh/ (example radius = 30px)

Answer (score 3):

Small but beautiful trick.

```
iframe,
object,
embed{
    border:5px solid rgba(255,255,255,0);
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px !important; 
    -ms-border-radius: 20px !important; 
    -o-border-radius: 20px !important;  
    border-radius: 20px !important;     
}
```

**[DEMO](https://creativform.makes.org/thimble/LTc1Njk0MDU0NA==/how-to-add-border-radius-on-embedded-youtube-video)**

Comment: This works in modern browsers, so +1 for a much more elegant solution; my answer was designed with legacy browsers (such as IE6) in mind, so the choice between these two methods ultimately boils down to whether or not you want (or need) to support such users.

Comment: Thank you man. I use this wery long time. I know that old IE and Safari made a problems becouse of that I give all solutions to people decide for themselves. In a future there will be enough only border-radius to be added and that's it. If we meet sometimes, I buy you a beer.