# youtube embeded video rounded corners when playing

Tags: css, youtube, rounded-corners

I know, there are some other questions like **how to make youtube embeded video with rounded corners** and some works, but only when it is in "not-played mode". **BUT when playing** (or stoppd after playing) **it looses the rounded corners**.

So, **how to keep rounded corners also during playing video?**

CSS code (not mine originally):

```
<style>
 iframe,
 object,
 embed
 {
  border:5px solid rgb(255,255,255);
  border:5px solid rgba(255,255,255,0);
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px !important; 
  -ms-border-radius: 20px !important; 
  -o-border-radius: 20px !important; 
  border-radius: 20px !important;
 }
</style>
```

HTML code:

```
<iframe width="380" height="214" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/vUuVYAYWy_Q?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: *try* setting overflow to hidden

Comment: Sure, I tried, but still the same problem, when playing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/1g1npqk6/1/)

[**Another technique using css `transforms` and `rotates`**](http://jsfiddle.net/skywalkar/uyfR6/)

[youtube embedded video as iframe with border-radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492250/youtube-embedded-video-as-iframe-with-border-radius)

```
iframe {
   border:20px solid red; /*your border-color*/
   border-radius: 20px !important;
}
```

The idea as you can see is in creating a "wrapper" around the iframe with the border.

To get a border smaller than this, you shall change 20px in both rules to same value.

Comment: it looks almost good, but I need it without the thick borders :( Exactly I need it without the border. (or just about 5px as in CSS above, which is not enough to save 20px rounding)

Comment: after editing i can accept **Another technique using css transforms and rotates**, thank you so much